# jhipster microservices client springcloud config with authorization header to jhipster registry

Tags: microservices, jhipster, spring-cloud-config, http-status-code-401, jhipster-registry

I am using jhipster 7 with springboot 2.5.4 for microservice applications development (DEV env)

I have setup jhipster registry server running on my localhost port 8761 with docker's help.

I am trying to access jhipster central springcloud config on

http://localhost:8761/config/application/prod/main

from all my microservices and gateway.

However, I got the following 401 warning when starting any of my microservice and gateway:

```
        ██╗ ██╗   ██╗ ████████╗ ███████╗   ██████╗ ████████╗ ████████╗ ███████╗ 
        ██║ ██║   ██║ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═══██╗ ██╔════╝ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═════╝ ██╔═══██╗
        ██║ ████████║    ██║    ███████╔╝ ╚█████╗     ██║    ██████╗   ███████╔╝
  ██╗   ██║ ██╔═══██║    ██║    ██╔════╝   ╚═══██╗    ██║    ██╔═══╝   ██╔══██║ 
  ╚██████╔╝ ██║   ██║ ████████╗ ██║       ██████╔╝    ██║    ████████╗ ██║  ╚██╗
   ╚═════╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝       ╚═════╝     ╚═╝    ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝

:: JHipster   :: Running Spring Boot 2.5.4 ::
:: https://www.jhipster.tech ::

2021-11-04 17:54:01.411  WARN 23468 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: 401 Unauthorized: [{
  "timestamp" : "2021-11-05T00:54:01.400+00:00",
  "status" : 401,
  "error" : "Unauthorized",
  "message" : "",
  "path" : "/config/application/prod/main"
}]
2021-11-04 17:54:01.415  INFO 23468 --- [           main] com.okta.developer.alert.AlertApp        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: dev,api-docs
2021-11-04 17:54:02.551 DEBUG 23468 --- [           main] i.g.r.utils.RxJava2OnClasspathCondition  : RxJava2 related Aspect extensions are not activated, because RxJava2 is not on the classpath.
2021-11-04 17:54:02.552 DEBUG 23468 --- [           main] i.g.r.utils.ReactorOnClasspathCondition  : Reactor related Aspect extensions are not activated because Resilience4j Reactor module is not on the classpath.
```

This is one of my spring cloud config from **application-dev.yml** (not the bootstrap.yml as I am not sure if do have to put my configs into bootstrap.yml)

```
spring:
  devtools:
    restart:
      enabled: true
      additional-exclude: static/**
    livereload:
      enabled: false # we use Webpack dev server + BrowserSync for livereload
  jackson:
    serialization:
      indent-output: true
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@localhost:8761/config
      # name of the config server's property source (file.yml) that we want to use
      name: application
      profile: prod
      label: main # toggle to switch to a different version of the configuration as stored in git
      # it can be set to any label, branch or commit of the configuration source Git repository
```

I am using keycloak as my oauth server, I believe I need to send an authorization header along with the GET request to /config/application/prod/main.

My central config looks like this:

```
{
  "name" : "application",
  "profiles" : [ "prod" ],
  "label" : "main",
  "version" : null,
  "state" : null,
  "propertySources" : [ {
    "name" : "file:central-config/localhost-config/application.yml",
    "source" : {
      "configserver.name" : "Docker JHipster Registry",
      "configserver.status" : "Connected to the JHipster Registry running in Docker",
      "jhipster.security.authentication.jwt.base64-secret" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone" : "http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@localhost:8761/eureka/"
    }
  } ]
}
```

Can someone help on how can I get rid of this 401 error and retrieve the central config successfully?

Comment: Have you set `oauth2` profile for starting the registry? Also your configurations use basic authentication not oauth2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spent some time to do investigation. The error is caused by the incorrect basic auth proile setup in my gateway and microservices.

I noticed that the config in **application-*.yml** showing below contains a registry password

```
jhipster:
  xxxxxxxxx
  registry:
    password: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

and I thought that was good enough for my microservices to retrieve spring cloud config from jhipster registry, but it is actually not. My microservices actually trying to find registry password from **bootstrap-*.yml**, and it failed to retrieve the correct password as I did not fill it with the appropriate value. So what I did is in **bootstrap-*.yml** made an update on the registry password

```
jhipster:
  registry:
    password: <correct_password>
```

and now the issue resolved

```
        ██╗ ██╗   ██╗ ████████╗ ███████╗   ██████╗ ████████╗ ████████╗ ███████╗
        ██║ ██║   ██║ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═══██╗ ██╔════╝ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═════╝ ██╔═══██╗
        ██║ ████████║    ██║    ███████╔╝ ╚█████╗     ██║    ██████╗   ███████╔╝
  ██╗   ██║ ██╔═══██║    ██║    ██╔════╝   ╚═══██╗    ██║    ██╔═══╝   ██╔══██║
  ╚██████╔╝ ██║   ██║ ████████╗ ██║       ██████╔╝    ██║    ████████╗ ██║  ╚██╗
   ╚═════╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝       ╚═════╝     ╚═╝    ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝

:: JHipster   :: Running Spring Boot 2.5.4 ::
:: https://www.jhipster.tech ::

2021-11-08 11:36:28.507  INFO 3872 --- [           main] com.okta.developer.store.StoreApp        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: dev,api-docs
2021-11-08 11:36:29.639 DEBUG 3872 --- [           main] i.g.r.utils.RxJava2OnClasspathCondition  : RxJava2 related Aspect extensions are not activated, because RxJava2 is not on the classpath.
2021-11-08 11:36:29.641 DEBUG 3872 --- [           main] i.g.r.utils.ReactorOnClasspathCondition  : Reactor related Aspect extensions are not activated because Resilience4j Reactor module is not on the classpath.
2021-11-08 11:36:29.656 DEBUG 3872 --- [           main] i.g.r.utils.RxJava2OnClasspathCondition  : RxJava2 related Aspect extensions are not activated, because RxJava2 is not on the classpath.
```

@Gaël Marziou, you are correct that I only setup the basic auth instead of oauth, and it is good enough for me to retrieve the config as of this fix: [commit 452728a](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/pull/337)